# How do I fix "Failed to sync vcpu reg" error?

Tags: android, android-emulator, intel, haxm

I'm trying to use the Intel HAX x86 emulator for Windows (8, if that matters).  I installed everything and created an AVD for the android version, and everything appears correct, but when I run it, I get this output:

```
Starting emulator for AVD 'x86_QVGA_Level10'
emulator: device fd:1044
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode
emulator: Failed to sync vcpu reg
emulator: Failed to sync HAX vcpu context
```

and the emulator won't run.  The significant part of this error `(Failed to sync vcpu reg)` is not mentioned ANYWHERE online, except in the [source code for the HAX itself](http://mirror.yongbok.net/pub/linux/android/repository/external/qemu/target-i386/hax-all.c), but I can't figure out how to make any sense of this.

Can anyone advise about how to get past this error?  I really need to get this working, because debugging on device and in the default emulators is painfully slow.

Comment: Just wanted to note that I was pulled off this project right after asking this question and never had the chance to try any of these solutions, so I don't know what the correct answer is! Should I pick the top voted answer and just accept it?

Comment: @JoshuaFrank: Nope just leave as-is. Sadly.

Answer (score 373):

Make sure you don't have any virtual machines running.  In my case, I had genymotion running which was causing this error.

Comment: This was exactly my problem and solution as well. Thanks!

Comment: Or even having virtualbox opened without any VM running for me

Comment: Got this issue on Mac. After turn off VBox it started to work.

Comment: Exactly my problem as well, forgot I had a VirtualBox VM running

Comment: Yep me too, had Genymotion running

Comment: I also had to restart my computer ... may have had something else running as well.

Comment: I also forgot I was toying with Docker and had a VBox VM running. I launched VirtualBox, stopped the VM and still got the error! I had to quit VirtualBox entirely to launch my emulator.

Comment: Worked when I stopped Virtualbox with boot2docker.

Comment: Thanks, should have thought of that. Had a Vagrant box up.

Comment: Why can't Genymotion and emulator run at the same time??

Comment: I had to stop all mu docker machines :( `docker-machine stop <machine>`

Comment: Is there a way to allow VBox running?

Comment: Might also happen when you are using Docker, check of a Virtualbox instance running in the background.

Comment: Half a year ago I had the same error and landed on the same answer which i already upvoted, kek.

Comment: I had Docker (on Mac) running. Stopping it fixed things for me.

Comment: In my case I had docker running, after closing it all is working

Comment: OMG Thanks a lot. It was exactly my problem. I spent more than 6 hours searching

Comment: Thank you! Here I had this problem in Mac OS X Sierra 10.12.3 (16D32) and noticed that a native Docker daemon was running.After stopped, it worked seamless.

Comment: I tried to configure multiple parameter on the "SDK Settings". I t was not helping. I stopped docker service, which was running in background. Opened virtualbox and closed again. Emulator started working :)

Answer (score 68):

I had virtualbox running. Killing the VM allowed allowed the emulator to run.

Comment: Thanks, would have never thought of that. Had a Vagrant box up.

Comment: Same here, docker-machine (boot2docker / virtualbox) was running.

Comment: Just another confirmation.  I stopped my Virtual box instance, and my emulator started right up. FYI my virtual device was using CPU/ABI=x86, and I was running on a macbook pro.

Comment: this is really a problem for me.. Im running a php app which provides api in virtual box on my macbook and I can't develop android app which needs to connect to that api... I guess I will need to deploy the php app on some server and develop on that, oh well

Comment: this worked ,my virtualbox was running in background ,now i really want both of them to work

Comment: For me it was VMware Workstation. I don’t know how to completely close it. I have no virtual machine running but Android Emulator still does not work. I thought it was some system services that I cannot easily close, so I uninstalled VMWare Workstation 15.5. Now the error has gone and Android Emulator is working well.

Answer (score 61):

If you are running Docker you would have to take the virtual machine down

`docker-machine stop default`

This assumes your docker machine is called `default`. If you want to check the name use
`docker-machine ls`

A simpler solution; open virtuabox and stop the vm :-)

Comment: Wow this was it for me. Crazy. How did you figure that out?

Comment: researching for the issue on google :-) and adding a little more explanation to it

Comment: If you are on a Mac and Docker app is running at the taskbar, close it too, even if docker-machine ls gives you nothing

Answer (score 18):

I had this problem. For me it was the HAXM version.

When you get a new version of HAMX through the SDK Manager, it tells you that it is installed. It is not. You must go to this folder:

> <Android SDK>\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager\

and run *intelhaxm-android.exe* manually. In my case, I had 1.0.6 and upgraded to 1.1.

I think that what caused the error in the first place was that some other part of the SDK that I had updated needed 1.1.

Comment: Similar issue but inverted: I had installed manually HAXM v7.8.0 following Android Studio suggestions because it could not be installed automatically, but v7.8.0 dropped support for older qemu versions that Android Studio uses, so I had to uninstall and downgrade to v7.6.5 installed through `Android Studio > Tools > SDK Manager > SDK Tools > Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer)`

Comment: Similar as @gaborous mentioned, I got mine solved by installing older HAXM version - https://github.com/intel/haxm/releases/download/v7.7.1/haxm-windows_v7_7_1.zip

Comment: Thank you @gaborous. I uninstalled HAXM and installed again and it now works!

Comment: Thank you both for your feedbacks! I thought I experienced a rare issue, but seeing how many upvotes and comments I received in this short timespan, it seems more common than I thought, I now added this solution as an answer.

Answer (score 14):

As mentioned by other answers, make sure no VirtualBox and docker service is running with following command in mac. (`systemctl` in Linux)

```
$ launchctl list | grep 'VirtualBox\|docker'
-       0   com.docker.helper
640     0   com.docker.docker.2032
31736   0   org.virtualbox.app.VirtualBox.948
```

If so, kill the `VBox` and `docker` service.

```
launchctl stop org.virtualbox.app.VirtualBox.948
launchctl stop com.docker.docker.2032
```

Answer (score 14):

Do you have HP SureClick running? I had the same problem on the HP laptop until I disabled it.

**HP SureClick** is a security protection program which runs "unsafe" programs in micro-VMs. It may also be called **HP Wolf Security** on your machine, which is the new name for it, although under the hood (e.g. folders, dialogs etc) it's still called SureClick. It may have some processes visible in Task Manager with a prefix of "Br", which stands for Bromium.

Similarly to other answers, it cannot be running at the same time as Android Emulator, as it is basically a virtual machine.

Here are some steps to disable it (not all may be required but this worked for me):

1. Right click on "HP SureClick" or "HP Wolf" in your system tray and select "Disable Threat Containment". It will pop up a dialog asking for the reason (optional), so just click OK
2. Right click on the icon again and select "Disable Malware Protection"
3. Click Start, type "services", open the Services window and set all "HP SureClick" services to disabled by right-clicking on each -> Properties -> change startup type to Disabled (for me there were 3 such services)
4. Restart the computer

After doing this, I was able to use Android Emulator again :)

Comment: Please elaborate your solution more precisely, with details about disabling.

Comment: @momt99 I added a lot more details to the answer, hopefully it's clearer now and helps some people

Comment: This was the fix for me. I have spent hours and hours looking and this solved it.

Answer (score 12):

1. Stop GENYMOTION (open VirtualBox instance if any instance is running, stop it).
2. Open AndroidStudio -> Run AVD Manager-> run AndroidStudio virtual device.

Latest Android Emulators are not able to run in parallel with GENYMOTION

Comment: Or stop docker as well

Answer (score 10):

"vcpu reg"  are "Virtual CPU REGisters" that exist on many processors that have things like multiple cores, hyperthreading, or other features that enable higher layers to believe that there is more than one CPU present when there isn't -- such as today's x86s. No reason to go in to detail -- you can imagine that getting a coherent, single "virtual CPU context" is necessary for the kind of hardware virtualization that HAX offers.

Normally, it's not a problem to run multiple virtual machines of various sorts simultaneously. But if one of them crashes, or misbehaves, or just decides to be a hog, HAX might find that it just can't put together a coherent virtual machine, because it can't  sync a virtual CPU context for itself. It'd be like trying to run a real machine with no CPU.

Bottom line is open task manager and kill things that you don't need and that look like they might be holding virtual machine resources. In the worst case, a reboot is almost certain to fix the problem.

Answer (score 5):

Quick steps:

1. Stop all VirtualBox Virtual Machines (i.e. vagrant halt), quit VirtualBox.
2. All docker-machines should be stopped, too. Quit Docker.

Answer (score 5):

This happened to me also when I was trying  to run both VirtualBox and Android emulator in a MacOS machine. As others have mentioned above currently it is not possible to run both (i.e. VirtualBox and X86 -Intel based emulator) in MacOS and not sure about the other platforms. 
If we need to run both we can choose ARM based emulator. (arm based emulators are normally slow)

Answer (score 4):

I was getting the same error. I'm guessing there are various reasons for this error, but in my case it was because of a service named ".NCG". The service is Network Content Guard by Inka Entworks, and seems to be some type of DRM solution. Once uninstalled, the emulator worked fine using HAX.

Comment: I don't have that software, but it is a good clue about other, similar programs.  How on earth did you discover that this was the problem?

Answer (score 4):

In my case, it turned out this problem was caused by having a webcam selected as "Front Camera" in the settings for the AVD. Setting it to "Emulated" fixed this problem for me.

Answer (score 4):

I faced this issue because I had my virtual box running with Ubuntu on it. When I shut down my virtual box I did not face this issue.

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error on my windows 8 install.

Things you could try:

- lower the amount of memory for the emulated device (and/or close other applications)
- disable GPU emulation
- remove the pass-through webcam

For me, the error occurs when I try to attach a physical webcam to the emulated android instance.

Comment: I'll give these a try and report back.  Thanks!

Comment: Funny for me was the solution to enable the GPU emulation.

Answer (score 3):

This kept failing until I changed it to [x] Use Host GPU as shown in pic.

[image: AVD Set up]

Comment: Yep - same for me. In the config.ini of the AVD (old one?) the property was set to: hw.gpu.enabled=no. after changing it to yes - everything works :)

Answer (score 3):

I'm running boot2docker vm, just down it solved the issue.

`boot2docker down`

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you don't have any virtual machines running. In my case, I had genymotion running which was causing this error. when i kill genymotion's Process and kill all Oracle VM VirtualBox related process then it work 
by wangshiming 
don't thankyou me

Answer (score 2):

Ya, i had virtual box running and was getting this error, shutting it down fixed the error.

Answer (score 2):

I was on a mac and had this problem. I did not think I was running a VM (I have vbox but it isn't running). I restarted my computer and before starting any other apps I tried the emulator and it works fine.

Comment: Exactly, I had vbox running. When I tuned off then emulator start working again.

Answer (score 2):

This is the VirtualBox ticket - https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/14294

Answer (score 2):

Fixed the problem by changing current version of Java within Windows from Java 8 x64 to Java 7 x86.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, VirtualBox VMs have to be stopped. I also had to stop Docker for Mac. The error message only mentions VirtualBox, which confused me a little until I realized Docker for Mac is running xhyve.

Answer (score 1):

If your CPU supports throttling (like Intel's [SpeedStep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpeedStep)) try to disable that feature in your BIOS. It's kind of a quickfix but at least it worked.

Comment: It seems like CPU throttling is not responsible for this error. The error appears in my case if a VirtualBox VM is currently running.

Answer (score 1):

I think it must be a variety of reasons cause this failure. In my case, since I installed the Google input method software, "Failed to sync vcpu reg" appeared. This was the one and only change before normal working. So, after uninstall the Google Input software, it was recovered.just a little reference, although I can't believe this solution for long time either.

Answer (score 1):

I had the **Windows Virtual PC** running (on Windows of course). Once I turned off, the emulator went fine.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to launch a Gingerbread 2.3.3 x86 emulator and it would not launch. Changing from x86 to arm made the problem go away.

Comment: This fixed it for me. Just switching to ARM. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For me, the only thing that worked using adv on MacOs Yosemite, is setting the processor to `ARM` (native CPU of the device - standard 4" Nexus).

Answer (score 1):

If you are having any virtual machines running, suspend them and try again.

Answer (score 1):

For me the answer was to set `Enable keyboard input` to true under the advanced settings of the virtual device.

This was the first option I changed on the device, so it is possible that the act of changed an option fixes the error as well based on the wide array of answers above.

Note: I've confirmed previously that no VM's are running.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the anwer for this question.
I had exactly the same problem and it was completely solved.

Virtual device or webcam is rarely the cause of your problem.

**Just install mainboard chipset driver.**

I recommend you to use 3DP chipset autoinstaller.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

For me it was google appengine running locally.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like in your environment variables on your system (for me on Window 7), setting the "Path" system variable (not user variable) to "*sdk_install_location*\tools\lib" e.g: "C:\Users\android_sdk\tools\lib" solved the problem for me.

Check out the "Tips and Tricks" section at this webpage: https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-windows for more info (if link is dead/doesn't work just google "Installation Instructions for Intel HAX").

Answer (score 0):

For those developers whose local environment leverages a VM (e.g. Homestead), simply halt the VM before launching the Android emulator. Restarting it after will allow both to run in parallel, but you're likely going to run into severe performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

I had installed manually HAXM v7.8.0 following Android Studio suggestions because it could not be installed automatically, but v7.8.0 dropped support for older qemu versions that Android Studio uses, so I had to uninstall and downgrade to v7.6.5, which I installed through `Android Studio > Tools > SDK Manager > SDK Tools > Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer)`. HAXM v7.7.1 also works according to other users feedbacks.

This is kind of similar but inverted issue that John Delaney reported in another answer. I already wrote the above as a comment, I write it now as an answer since it appears it helped several people so it seems pretty common currently (as of December 2022 / January 2023).

Answer (score -1):

I reduced the size of the VM memory allocated and it seems to have fixed it.

Comment: This answer would be improved if you would provide guidance on _how_ to reduce the VM size.

Comment: thisrunson meant to say the VM Heap -- Although it would've helped if mentioned the size set to. Mine i s at 64 default.  But that wasn't my problem. I had to turn on [x] Use Host GPU