# Android Studio - Error accepting connection, aborting

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new to `Android Studio` come from `Eclipse`. I am creating and running simple application in android emulator. It's working fine. Now I closed my emulator and re nun my application. I am getting this error message in logcat.

```
C:\Users\Vijay\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Development_AVD
emulator: device fd:596
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode
emulator: Failed to sync vcpu reg
emulator: Failed to sync HAX vcpu context
Error accepting connection, aborting
```

I can not execute my application. I restart the Android studio. But no luck. If I restart the computer and execute the appliction mean it's working fine.

Please let me know what mistake I am doing? How to execute the application without restart the computer. And how to close the emulator safely after work completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution from [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18404882).

Make sure you don't have any `virtual machines` running. In my case, I am developing windows phone app also. So windows phone emulator uses the virtual machine. That's why I am getting this error. After closing my windows phone emulator my android emulator start smoothly. But I didn't face this problem when I am using Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `Windows` then open `Windows Task Manager`. Kill or `end process` the `adb.exe` process and try to run your app again.

Comment: Go to `C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe.`

Double click on `adb.exe`. I think that might help you.

Comment: Hi.. Thanks for your reply. But I found the solution from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18404882).