# Android Emulator is not running (Error)

Tags: android, android-studio

Android emulator is not running and is showing this error:

> D:\Software\tools\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd
>   Nexus_4_API_23 emulator: device fd:748 HAXM is working and emulator
>   runs in fast virt mode emulator: Failed to sync vcpu reg emulator:
>   Failed to sync HAX vcpu context Error accepting connection, aborting

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I fix "Failed to sync vcpu reg" error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17024538/how-do-i-fix-failed-to-sync-vcpu-reg-error)

Comment: is your hyperv disabled?

Answer (score 2):

just shut down all virtual boxes.  Most people have genymotion running which causes the issue. run one emulator at a time and virtual device.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to install the HAXM on your machine. To do so just follow the path

Your SDK\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager

there you can install the intelhaxm-android. if its giving you the error thats mean your machine has turnd off support virtualization or does not support. For understanding this and how to work around to enable this I would suggest you read [this](https://www.thenewboston.com/forum/topic.php?id=3853) little discussion

Comment: Avd is running fine.I close amulater and start again but it did not work showhing that Error accepting connection, aborting.

Comment: then you need to restart your machine