# How to launch AVD while keep running docker

Tags: android, docker, android-emulator

I have installed docker on my mac machine. If I launch a emulator when the default docker machine is running, I will get below errors. It works fine to stop the docker machine. Is there a way to allow them both running together?

Starting emulator for AVD 'x86_QVGA_Level10'
emulator: device fd:1044
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode
emulator: Failed to sync vcpu reg
emulator: Failed to sync HAX vcpu context

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17024538/how-do-i-fix-failed-to-sync-vcpu-reg-error/40924524#40924524

Answer (score 0):

Support for simultaneously running docker and emulator for mac was added at [HAXM 6.1.1](https://github.com/intel/haxm/wiki/HAXM-6.x-Release-Archive#haxm-v611):

```
- Fixed coexistence with VirtualBox and Docker on macOS. (b.android.com/197915)
```

Make sure you have updated to the latest version (6.2.1 at the time of writing).