# How do i fix "emulator: Failed to sync vcpu reg" error in ionic mac android emulator error

Tags: android, macos, ionic-framework

ionic build android command failed with the error:

emulator: Failed to sync vcpu reg
emulator: Failed to sync HAX vcpu context

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I fix "Failed to sync vcpu reg" error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17024538/how-do-i-fix-failed-to-sync-vcpu-reg-error)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If docker is working, stop it.

For example:

```
$ docker-machine ls

NAME   ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL
dev    *        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.104:2376

$ docker-machine stop dev
$ docker-machine ls

NAME   ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL
dev    *        virtualbox   Stopped
```

Comment: In my case I had to quit Docker App, because it uses another virtual machine, that is `docker-machine ls` shows that default VM is already stopped.

Comment: It works for me after I quit the Docker app in the mac.