# How to get logs of Android Emulator crash on Mac?

Tags: android, crash, emulation, android-virtual-device

Android Emulator AVD closes on Mac as soon it is opened. How to check the error logs? In which location is it stored to examine the issue?

Edit: I happened to fix the issue myself. Answer below. In my case, I had to quit Docker.

Comment: read this http://esausilva.com/2010/10/02/how-to-set-up-adb-android-debug-bridge-in-mac-osx/

Comment: @Tauqir Thank you for your help but that info is for ADB. I'm actually asking regarding AVD Emulator crashes.

Comment: oh my mistake. It seems you already fixed it. good work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To see the logs when launching the emulator, I had to use the terminal directly.

First,
`$ANDROID_SDK_HOME/tools/emulator @device_name`. For me it was `/Users/rakshakhegde/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator @Nexus_5X_API_O`.

In the logs it said that `emulator: Failed to sync vcpu reg`. So from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17024538/how-do-i-fix-failed-to-sync-vcpu-reg-error) I realized that any other running VM can interfere to open the emulator. In my case, it was Docker running in the background. After I killed it, got my emulator running.

Answer (score -1):

adb logcat works for me while running the emulator from AVD Manager in Android Studio 3.2.1