# android AVD (Emulator) exit

Tags: android, android-studio, emulation, android-virtual-device

I cannot open the emulator, each time I Press launch avd. the emulato exit immidately before launching.

and it seems like there is no integration ? or something wrong as I have the below error: emulator unknow. 
even though I have an emulator. [image]

I don't even know what sort of issues is this!
as it exits without any error message.

Edit:

I solved the issue by simply reinstalling Intel HAXM

Comment: Try checking the [AVD Logs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42997120/1790644).

Answer (score 0):

When this type of problem happens, best way is to make sure you have followed below points correctly.

- You have proper SDK installed
- You have Intel HAXM & virtualization option enabled in your BIOS
- Configure emulator correctly, download the Intel X86 Atom system image for better performance.
- Disable and then Enable ADB Integration
- User arm instead of x86 if you have AMD processor when creating emulator.(In most of case)

Comment: yes, I even disabled and enabled the integration. 
it was running before...
I might reinstall Intel