# Can not run my app on emulator - error while loading state for instance 0x0 of device 'goldfish_pipe'

Tags: android-emulator

Yesterday I've created Pixel 3 XL device to test my app on emulator. It was working yesterday but today I'm getting these errors when I try to run my app.

```
14:58   Emulator: C:\Users\Mert\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe: error while loading state for instance 0x0 of device 'goldfish_pipe'

14:58   Emulator: deleteSnapshot: for default_boot

14:58   Emulator: Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Deleting device from AVD Manager and creating a new one(I created the same one) worked for me

Comment: This didn't work for me.  I had just downloaded the kernel for the first time.  So I deleted it and downloaded it again and it crashed with the same error.

Answer (score 30):

for me, I have installed a newer version of [HAXM](https://github.com/intel/haxm/releases)  and it worked perfectly

Comment: this should be accepted answer. for some reason mine was on low version. upgraded and works fine now! thanks mate

Comment: Watch out that the newest version of HAXM doesn't guarantee that the problem will be solved. Please check my answer on this question.

Answer (score 3):

[image: Download the google play version marked in yellow rather google API.]

Download the google play version marked in yellow rather google API.
Creating emulator again with image from google play will also make sure reinstallation of HAXM.

Answer (score 2):

I solve this issue within Android Studio SDK Manager, update to a newer version of Android SDK Build-Tools and Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer), in the HAXM installer wizzard I put 4GB RAM size. 
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EC7YI.png)

Answer (score 2):

In my case I deleted the old devices and downloaded the Google Play play version image and manually changed adb.exe file.

Answer (score 2):

Actually the working HAXM version isn't always the newests, as other answers suggest. I had HAXM version 7.8.0 (latest version ATM) installed on my Windows, but even though I was getting the question error (`error while loading state for instance 0x0 of device 'goldfish_pipe'`). I had it installed via its own installer, outside Android Studio, because I was getting error trying to install HAXM via Android Studio.

Then I had the idea to uninstall that latest version (7.8.0 ATM) and again try to install the version shown in Android Studio (7.6.5 ATM) via Android Studio itself, and it worked! So I realized the steps I needed to take in order to successfully install HAXM via installer (step 1 shown [here](https://github.com/intel/haxm/blob/master/docs/manual-windows.md#one-time-setup)) also fixed the problem trying to install it via Android Studio! And finally, after hours and hours of harrassment, I could successfully launch a virtual device on the emulator.

Below is the step for successfully installing HAXM (taken from [here](https://github.com/intel/haxm/blob/master/docs/manual-windows.md#one-time-setup)):
[image]

At last but not least, make sure you have no other virtual machine running! It would throw you at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17024538/how-do-i-fix-failed-to-sync-vcpu-reg-error)'s error.

Comment: Thank you so much, I had the exact same situation. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

My case is:

- disable Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) in Android Studio SDK Manager
- uninstall HAXM as a result
- enable again Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) in Android Studio SDK Manager
- install HAXM as a result
- recreate emulated AVD
- finally works for Me