# How do I fix Android emulator crash from "failed to sync vcpu reg"

Tags: android

I am using Android Studio emulator, but it keeps crashing upon opening. I get failed to sync vcpu reg error multiple times in the output and nothing else.

I have tried the solutions to similar questions posted on here to no avail. I tried: reinstalling HAXM, I don't have the docker application, I used BIOS to check that VT-x and VT-d are both enabled. I don't get any logcat from Android Studio.

[Attached is picture of the output from running the emulator from cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tuF8q.png)

This question is different from apparent duplicates because my emulator worked the day before. I don't have any virtual machines running. The only difference is that my laptop auto updated last night.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I fix "Failed to sync vcpu reg" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17024538/how-do-i-fix-failed-to-sync-vcpu-reg-error)

Comment: SUGGESTIONS: 1) Try running from inside Android Studio, 2) Try running a simple "hello world" app,  If the emulator still won't come up with a minimal "Hello World" in either "Run" or "Debug" from A/S, then 3) Create a new AVD, with minimal features.  Please post back what you find.

Comment: 1) Same issue, 2) same issue, 3) same issue, Emulator: failed to sync vcpu reg

Comment: I am wondering, could new firewall or antivirus settings be the problem. As I stated above, my laptop just updated and the emulator stopped working.

Comment: What was "auto-updated"? Windows 10?  Any chance you can roll the update back and re-test?  Or delete Android Studio/Android SDK and reinstall?  And yes, anything is "possible".  But my guess is that you made a "Windows Update", and that update contained some "security feature" that broke something the AVD emulator needs...

Comment: Yes the windows was updated and I checked the details: regular windows and a security update as well. After uninstalling the updates, I get a new error show up: "emulator: ERROR: AdbHostServer.cpp:93: Unable to connect to adb daemon on port: 5037". EDIT: Nevermind, I removed the set partition size and that error went away.

Comment: Q: Did you resolve the "unable to connect ... on port 5037" error?  Q: Are you still getting "Failed to sync vcpu reg", or did you resolve that, too?  Please update your post.

Comment: Yes after taking out partition-size 512 command or when running directly from android studio I only get failed to sync vcpu reg error.

Comment: Q: Have you tried rolling back the Windows update: https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/roll-back-windows-10-creators-update?  Or, alternatively, a) uninstall A/S and the SDK, b) reboot, c) re-install A/S?

Comment: So I tried to roll back windows but I found out that since my windows updated twice it will not allow me roll back before the first one. Additionally, I uninstalled AS and the SDK and sdk cache, then rebooted and reinstalled AS and the Sdk and HAXM. However, I still get the failed to sync vcpu reg error and nothing else. I open to more suggestions, and have to finish a project so I am running android studio and the emulator on another laptop which runs the emulator fine.

Comment: If you need to finish your assignment and you've got a laptop that works - cool! More power to you!  Final suggestions: 1) Try turning off your A/V and see if that helps (a pure shot in the dark), 2) scour task manager for *ANYTHING* that might be doing "virtualization" of *ANY* kind: Docker, VBox, VMWare, etc etc.  and 3) Consider buying a cheap ($20) physical handset for testing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I solved this problem on my HP laptop by uninstalling HP SureClick.

Comment: Later down the line, I ran into the same issue and uninstalling sure click worked. Thanks! The other method I tried by paulsm4 was only a temporary fix.

Comment: Yep, this worked for me too. After two whole days of researching, uninstalling, reinstalling, etc...THIS got the emulator working again. Uninstalled HP SureClick and it worked again. Thanks #eje

Comment: Are you kidding me? What a logical reason for emulator not working. How could this take you guys so long to figure it out... Thanks a lot for tip.

Comment: Saved my life. Tried reinstalling android studio multiple times!

Answer (score 6):

I am using Windows 10 and tried almost everything the internet had to offer to fix this issue (the Virtual Machine in Android Studio loaded but then closed almost immediately)

The fix I found was to enable "Virtual Machine Platform" on Windows features.

Instructions:

1. Right click on the Windows button and select 'Apps and Features'
2. Select Programs and Features on the right under related settings
3. Select the checkbox below

[CHECKBOX TO CLICK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sjjk.png)

You then get prompted to restart - after that, everything worked for me ! ...hope it does for you !

Comment: have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17024538/how-do-i-fix-failed-to-sync-vcpu-reg-error

Comment: Worked for me. Was ready to give up. The guide here - https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration shows to specifcally disable Virtual Machine Platform. Re-enabled it and restarted and my emulator booted up!

Comment: Like the above comments, I also banged my head against the wall with this for an entire day.  Enabling VMP fixed the issue.

Comment: Great. This saved a lot of time

Answer (score 3):

I had this same problem and all the solutions here did not appear to fix it. Strangely enough I managed to fix it by turning windows virtual machine platform ON, even though it very specifically says [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration) that this is something that should be turned OFF.

Comment: Thanks for the link this provided me with the info I needed to fix this reliably. So it turns out that while turning virtual mahcine platform worked for you, I needed to ensure that all these were also disabled when disabling hyper-v: Virtual Machine Platform, Windows Hypervisor Platform, Windows Sandbox, Core Isolation, Credential Guard. Since those implicitly activate hyper-v which doesn't allow the android emulator to run properly.

Comment: Emulator booted up for me after re-enabling Virtual Machine Platform!

Answer (score 0):

I tried what paulsm4 said and the emulator works now. I was looking around in my anti virus settings and found something that uses virtualization. I just turned it on rebooted and then back off and rebooted. The emulator runs!

[image: security setting screenshot]