# Android studio avd problem: emulator process for AVD has terminated

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, intel, android-virtual-device

I'm facing issues with running android studio emulators. I get the following error:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/19YQsrAzXh8MR97lzXWlHRXgOjc-BH0O2/view?usp=sharing

**My System Settings:**

- Name: HP Zbook Fury 15 G7 Mobile Workstation
- CPU: Intel core i7-10850H
- GPU: Nvidia quadro T2000 Max-Q
- Ram: 32 GB

*Note that I don't have any virtual machine installed neither I'm using docker*

**AVD settings:**

- Device Type: Pixel 4
- API: 30
- Target: Android 11.0(Google Play)
- CPU/ABI x86

*list whit all device settings:* [link to file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1g4X7xNi70ppU3aJhUlLNGhMer63l8qSC/view?usp=sharing)

*Note that I also tried using Pixel 3 as device type, and I tried different target and CPU/ABI as stated in "things I tried to do"*

***Things I tried to do:***

- re-install Android emulator SDK
- re-install Intel HAXM
- re-download system image
- using R x86_64 image (both with and without Google APIs)
- changing GPU mode to "host"
- wipe date from the avd and cold boot
- disabling sure hp sure run
- disabling hp sure click from the hp client security

Thanks in advance for the answers

Comment: Can you try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/64646820/17490003

Comment: @PamelaSarkisyan I tried to disable hp sure run as a whole and also tried to uncheck hp sure click in hp sure run settings (from hp client security). however, I can't find a stand-alone program for hp sure click dough checking the task manager led me to a folder called "Sure Click" inside the "HP" folder in the programs folder. If I'm doing something wrong in disabling hp sure click please let me know how I can do it properly.

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling it completely from the machine ?

Comment: @PamelaSarkisyan I can't find a way to uninstall only sure click and I would like not to uninstall the whole hp sure run. is there a way to make avd work without having to uninstall sure run?

Comment: Fair enough - [This stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61523744/17490003) specifies in details the steps needed to disable hp sure click

Comment: Thanks, It worked. the only difference is that in my version of hp wolf there is not possible to disable malware protection in the way stated in step 2 of the link you sent me. But I solved the issue by disabling hp security products in the hp client security dashboard under hp sure run

Comment: Great - I’m glad it worked :)

Answer (score 1):

**Solution was to disable Hp sure click and its services**
I followed the solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17024538/how-do-i-fix-failed-to-sync-vcpu-reg-error/61523744#61523744)
Thanks to @PamelaSarkisyan for providing me with the link.
However, I found that step 2 was not possible with my version of hp wolf, so I did the following:

1. Right-click on "HP SureClick" or "HP Wolf" in your system tray and select "Disable Threat Containment". It will pop up a dialog asking for the reason (optional), so just click OK *(as in the original post)*
2. Open "Hp Client Security Manager" (search it in the start menu or in the control panel). Click on "Hp Sure Run"
3. Under "Select Categories" uncheck "HP security products" and click send/apply. **Wait for 90 seconds**.
4. Click Start, type "services", open the Services window and set the following services startup type to disabled: "HP SureClick Endpoint Service", "HP SureClick Host Management Service", "HP SureClick Remote Management Service"
   ***Do that by right-clicking on each -> Properties -> change startup type to Disabled***  *(as in the original post)*
5. Restart your computer

Comment: Great that it worked! Which version of hp wolf do you use?