# Android Emulator Crashes on Windows 10 with HAXM 7.8.0

Tags: android, windows-10, android-virtual-device

I am running into an issue where I cannot run the Android emulator with seemingly any version of HAXM installed, including the latest version 7.8.0.  Below is the emulator log output using the verbose and show-kernal options.

Windows 10 build 19044.2364

openjdk version "11.0.12" 2021-07-20

```
INFO    | Android emulator version 31.3.14.0 (build_id 9322596) (CL:N/A)
INFO    | Found AVD name 'pixel_5_-_api_30'
INFO    | Found AVD target architecture: x86
INFO    | argv[0]: 'emulator'; program directory: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator'
VERBOSE |  Found directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\system-images\android-30\google_apis\x86\
emulator: INFO: Found systemPath C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\system-images\android-30\google_apis\x86\
INFO    | emuDirName: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator'
VERBOSE |  Found directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\system-images\android-30\google_apis\x86\
emulator: INFO: Found systemPath C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\system-images\android-30\google_apis\x86\
INFO    | Probing for C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\system-images\android-30\google_apis\x86\\kernel-ranchu-64: file exists
INFO    | try dir C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator
INFO    | Trying emulator path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe'
INFO    | Found target-specific 64-bit emulator binary: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe
INFO    | Adding library search path: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\lib64'
INFO    | Adding library search path: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\lib64\gles_swiftshader'
VERBOSE | Adding library search path for Qt: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\lib64\qt\lib'
VERBOSE | Silencing all qWarning(); use qCWarning(...) instead: QT_LOGGING_RULES=default.warning=false
VERBOSE | Setting Qt plugin search path: QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\lib64\qt\plugins
VERBOSE | Setting Qt to use software OpenGL: QT_OPENGL=software
VERBOSE | Setting QML to use software QtQuick2D: QMLSCENE_DEVICE=softwarecontext
VERBOSE | Overriding pre-existing bad Qt high dpi settings...
INFO    | Quoted param: ["C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe"]
INFO    | Quoted param: [-avd]
INFO    | Quoted param: [pixel_5_-_api_30]
INFO    | Quoted param: [-verbose]
INFO    | Quoted param: [-show-kernel]
VERBOSE | emulator: Running :C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe
VERBOSE | qemu backend: argv[00] = ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe""
VERBOSE | qemu backend: argv[01] = "-avd"
VERBOSE | qemu backend: argv[02] = "pixel_5_-_api_30"
VERBOSE | qemu backend: argv[03] = "-verbose"
VERBOSE | qemu backend: argv[04] = "-show-kernel"
VERBOSE | Concatenated backend parameters:  '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe" ' -avd pixel_5_-_api_30 -verbose -show-kernel
INFO    | Duplicate loglines will be removed, if you wish to see each indiviudal line launch with the -log-nofilter flag.
VERBOSE | autoconfig: -skin 1080x2340
VERBOSE | autoconfig: -skindir (null)
WARNING | unexpected system image feature string, emulator might not function correctly, please try updating the emulator.
VERBOSE | Unexpected feature list:
VERBOSE | Vulkan
VERBOSE | querying file version info API...
VERBOSE | found kernelbase.dll
VERBOSE | GetFileVersionInfoSizeW found. On Windows 10?
VERBOSE | GetFileVersionInfoW found. On Windows 10?
VERBOSE | VerQueryValueW found. Can query file versions
VERBOSE | queryFileVersionInfo: path not found: amdvlk64.dll
VERBOSE | querying file version info API...
VERBOSE | queryFileVersionInfo: path not found: amdvlk32.dll
VERBOSE | querying file version info API...
VERBOSE | autoconfig: -kernel C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\system-images\android-30\google_apis\x86\\kernel-ranchu-64
VERBOSE | Target arch = 'x86'
VERBOSE | Auto-config: -qemu -cpu qemu32
VERBOSE | Auto-detect: Kernel image requires new device naming scheme.
VERBOSE | Auto-detect: Kernel does not support YAFFS2 partitions.
VERBOSE | autoconfig: -ramdisk C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\system-images\android-30\google_apis\x86\\ramdisk.img
VERBOSE | Using initial system image: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\system-images\android-30\google_apis\x86\\system.img
VERBOSE | Using initial vendor image: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\system-images\android-30\google_apis\x86\\vendor.img
VERBOSE | autoconfig: -initdata C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\system-images\android-30\google_apis\x86\\userdata.img
VERBOSE | autoconfig: -cache C:\Users\username\.android\avd\pixel_5_-_api_30.avd\cache.img
VERBOSE | autoconfig: -sdcard C:\Users\username\.android\avd\pixel_5_-_api_30.avd\sdcard.img
VERBOSE | Increasing RAM size to 2048MB
VERBOSE | VM heap size 256MB is below hardware specified minimum of 512MB,setting it to that value
VERBOSE | System image is read only
INFO    | IPv4 server found: **REDACTED**
VERBOSE | Found 1 DNS servers:
VERBOSE |       **REDACTED**
VERBOSE | found magic skin width=1080 height=2340 bpp=16

VERBOSE | Creating ext4 userdata partition: C:\Users\username\.android\avd\pixel_5_-_api_30.avd\data
Creating filesystem with parameters:
    Size: 6442450944
    Block size: 4096
    Blocks per group: 32768
    Inodes per group: 8192
    Inode size: 256
    Journal blocks: 24576
    Label:
    Blocks: 1572864
    Block groups: 48
    Reserved block group size: 383
Created filesystem with 24/393216 inodes and 52345/1572864 blocks
VERBOSE | CPU Acceleration: working
VERBOSE | CPU Acceleration status: HAXM version 7.8.0 (4) is installed and usable.
VERBOSE | handleCpuAcceleration: feature check for hvf
VERBOSE | registered 'boot-properties' qemud service
VERBOSE | Adding boot property: 'qemu.cmdline' = 'androidboot.logcat=*:V androidboot.consolepipe=qemu_pipe,pipe:logcat'
VERBOSE | Adding boot property: 'qemu.logcat' = 'start'
VERBOSE | GPU emulation enabled using 'swiftshader_indirect' mode
VERBOSE | Initializing hardware OpenGLES emulation support
VERBOSE | create display 0
VERBOSE | setDisplayPose 0 x 0 y 0 w 1080 h 2340 dpi 0
INFO    | added library vulkan-1.dll
ERROR   | Failed to create Vulkan instance.
INFO    | configAndStartRenderer: setting vsync to 60 hz
VERBOSE | Found 1 DNS servers:
VERBOSE |      **REDACTED**
INFO    | Content of hardware configuration file:
INFO    |       hw.cpu.arch = x86
INFO    |       hw.cpu.model = qemu32
INFO    |       hw.cpu.ncore = 4
INFO    |       hw.ramSize = 2048
INFO    |       hw.screen = multi-touch
INFO    |       hw.mainKeys = false
INFO    |       hw.trackBall = false
INFO    |       hw.keyboard = true
INFO    |       hw.keyboard.lid = false
INFO    |       hw.keyboard.charmap = qwerty2
INFO    |       hw.dPad = false
INFO    |       hw.rotaryInput = false
INFO    |       hw.gsmModem = true
INFO    |       hw.gps = true
INFO    |       hw.battery = true
INFO    |       hw.accelerometer = true
INFO    |       hw.gyroscope = true
INFO    |       hw.audioInput = true
INFO    |       hw.audioOutput = true
INFO    |       hw.sdCard = true
INFO    |       hw.sdCard.path = C:\Users\username\.android\avd\pixel_5_-_api_30.avd\sdcard.img
INFO    |       disk.cachePartition = true
INFO    |       disk.cachePartition.path = C:\Users\username\.android\avd\pixel_5_-_api_30.avd\cache.img
INFO    |       disk.cachePartition.size = 66m
INFO    |       test.quitAfterBootTimeOut = -1
INFO    |       test.delayAdbTillBootComplete = 0
INFO    |       test.monitorAdb = 0
INFO    |       hw.lcd.width = 1080
INFO    |       hw.lcd.height = 2340
INFO    |       hw.lcd.depth = 16
INFO    |       hw.lcd.density = 440
INFO    |       hw.lcd.backlight = true
INFO    |       hw.lcd.vsync = 60
INFO    |       hw.gltransport = pipe
INFO    |       hw.gltransport.asg.writeBufferSize = 1048576
INFO    |       hw.gltransport.asg.writeStepSize = 4096
INFO    |       hw.gltransport.asg.dataRingSize = 32768
INFO    |       hw.gltransport.drawFlushInterval = 800
INFO    |       hw.displayRegion.0.1.xOffset = -1
INFO    |       hw.displayRegion.0.1.yOffset = -1
INFO    |       hw.displayRegion.0.1.width = 0
INFO    |       hw.displayRegion.0.1.height = 0
INFO    |       hw.displayRegion.0.2.xOffset = -1
INFO    |       hw.displayRegion.0.2.yOffset = -1
INFO    |       hw.displayRegion.0.2.width = 0
INFO    |       hw.displayRegion.0.2.height = 0
INFO    |       hw.displayRegion.0.3.xOffset = -1
INFO    |       hw.displayRegion.0.3.yOffset = -1
INFO    |       hw.displayRegion.0.3.width = 0
INFO    |       hw.displayRegion.0.3.height = 0
INFO    |       hw.display1.width = 0
INFO    |       hw.display1.height = 0
INFO    |       hw.display1.density = 0
INFO    |       hw.display1.xOffset = -1
INFO    |       hw.display1.yOffset = -1
INFO    |       hw.display1.flag = 0
INFO    |       hw.display2.width = 0
INFO    |       hw.display2.height = 0
INFO    |       hw.display2.density = 0
INFO    |       hw.display2.xOffset = -1
INFO    |       hw.display2.yOffset = -1
INFO    |       hw.display2.flag = 0
INFO    |       hw.display3.width = 0
INFO    |       hw.display3.height = 0
INFO    |       hw.display3.density = 0
INFO    |       hw.display3.xOffset = -1
INFO    |       hw.display3.yOffset = -1
INFO    |       hw.display3.flag = 0
INFO    |       hw.multi_display_window = false
INFO    |       hw.gpu.enabled = true
INFO    |       hw.gpu.mode = swiftshader_indirect
INFO    |       hw.initialOrientation = portrait
INFO    |       hw.camera.back = virtualscene
INFO    |       hw.camera.front = emulated
INFO    |       vm.heapSize = 512
INFO    |       hw.sensors.light = true
INFO    |       hw.sensors.pressure = true
INFO    |       hw.sensors.humidity = true
INFO    |       hw.sensors.proximity = true
INFO    |       hw.sensors.magnetic_field = true
INFO    |       hw.sensors.magnetic_field_uncalibrated = true
INFO    |       hw.sensors.gyroscope_uncalibrated = true
INFO    |       hw.sensors.orientation = true
INFO    |       hw.sensors.temperature = true
INFO    |       hw.sensors.rgbclight = false
INFO    |       hw.sensor.hinge = false
INFO    |       hw.sensor.hinge.count = 0
INFO    |       hw.sensor.hinge.type = 0
INFO    |       hw.sensor.hinge.sub_type = 0
INFO    |       hw.sensor.hinge.fold_to_displayRegion.0.1_at_posture = 1
INFO    |       hw.sensor.roll = false
INFO    |       hw.sensor.roll.count = 0
INFO    |       hw.sensor.roll.resize_to_displayRegion.0.1_at_posture = 6
INFO    |       hw.sensor.roll.resize_to_displayRegion.0.2_at_posture = 6
INFO    |       hw.sensor.roll.resize_to_displayRegion.0.3_at_posture = 6
INFO    |       hw.sensors.heart_rate = false
INFO    |       hw.sensors.wrist_tilt = false
INFO    |       hw.useext4 = true
INFO    |       hw.arc = false
INFO    |       hw.arc.autologin = false
INFO    |       hw.device.name = pixel_5
INFO    |       kernel.path = C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\system-images\android-30\google_apis\x86\\kernel-ranchu-64
INFO    |       kernel.newDeviceNaming = yes
INFO    |       kernel.supportsYaffs2 = no
INFO    |       disk.ramdisk.path = C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\system-images\android-30\google_apis\x86\\ramdisk.img
INFO    |       disk.systemPartition.initPath = C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\system-images\android-30\google_apis\x86\\system.img
INFO    |       disk.systemPartition.size = 3083m
INFO    |       disk.vendorPartition.initPath = C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\system-images\android-30\google_apis\x86\\vendor.img
INFO    |       disk.vendorPartition.size = 800m
INFO    |       disk.dataPartition.path = C:\Users\username\.android\avd\pixel_5_-_api_30.avd\userdata-qemu.img
INFO    |       disk.dataPartition.initPath = C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\system-images\android-30\google_apis\x86\\userdata.img
INFO    |       disk.dataPartition.size = 6g
INFO    |       disk.encryptionKeyPartition.path = C:\Users\username\.android\avd\pixel_5_-_api_30.avd\encryptionkey.img
INFO    |       PlayStore.enabled = false
INFO    |       avd.name = pixel_5_-_api_30
INFO    |       avd.id = pixel_5_-_api_30
INFO    |       fastboot.forceColdBoot = false
INFO    |       android.sdk.root = C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
INFO    |       android.avd.home = C:\Users\username\.android\avd
INFO    | .
INFO    | QEMU options list:
INFO    |        argv[00] = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe"
INFO    |        argv[01] = "-dns-server"
INFO    |        argv[02] = "**REDACTED**"
INFO    |        argv[03] = "-mem-path"
INFO    |        argv[04] = "C:\Users\username\.android\avd\pixel_5_-_api_30.avd\snapshots\default_boot\ram.img"
INFO    |        argv[05] = "-mem-file-shared"
INFO    |        argv[06] = "-serial"
INFO    |        argv[07] = "con:"
INFO    |        argv[08] = "-device"
INFO    |        argv[09] = "goldfish_pstore,addr=0xff018000,size=0x10000,file=C:\Users\username\.android\avd\pixel_5_-_api_30.avd\data\misc\pstore\pstore.bin"
INFO    |        argv[10] = "-cpu"
INFO    |        argv[11] = "android64"
INFO    |        argv[12] = "-enable-hax"
INFO    |        argv[13] = "-smp"
INFO    |        argv[14] = "cores=4"
INFO    |        argv[15] = "-m"
INFO    |        argv[16] = "2048"
INFO    |        argv[17] = "-lcd-density"
INFO    |        argv[18] = "440"
INFO    |        argv[19] = "-nodefaults"
INFO    |        argv[20] = "-kernel"
INFO    |        argv[21] = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\system-images\android-30\google_apis\x86\\kernel-ranchu-64"
INFO    |        argv[22] = "-initrd"
INFO    |        argv[23] = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\system-images\android-30\google_apis\x86\\ramdisk.img"
INFO    |        argv[24] = "-drive"
INFO    |        argv[25] = "if=none,index=0,id=system,if=none,file=C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\system-images\android-30\google_apis\x86\\system.img,read-only"
INFO    |        argv[26] = "-device"
INFO    |        argv[27] = "virtio-blk-pci,drive=system,modern-pio-notify"
INFO    |        argv[28] = "-drive"
INFO    |        argv[29] = "if=none,index=1,id=cache,if=none,file=C:\Users\username\.android\avd\pixel_5_-_api_30.avd\cache.img.qcow2,overlap-check=none,cache=unsafe,l2-cache-size=1048576"
INFO    |        argv[30] = "-device"
INFO    |        argv[31] = "virtio-blk-pci,drive=cache,modern-pio-notify"
INFO    |        argv[32] = "-drive"
INFO    |        argv[33] = "if=none,index=2,id=userdata,if=none,file=C:\Users\username\.android\avd\pixel_5_-_api_30.avd\userdata-qemu.img.qcow2,overlap-check=none,cache=unsafe,l2-cache-size=1048576"
INFO    |        argv[34] = "-device"
INFO    |        argv[35] = "virtio-blk-pci,drive=userdata,modern-pio-notify"
INFO    |        argv[36] = "-drive"
INFO    |        argv[37] = "if=none,index=3,id=encrypt,if=none,file=C:\Users\username\.android\avd\pixel_5_-_api_30.avd\encryptionkey.img.qcow2,overlap-check=none,cache=unsafe,l2-cache-size=1048576"
INFO    |        argv[38] = "-device"
INFO    |        argv[39] = "virtio-blk-pci,drive=encrypt,modern-pio-notify"
INFO    |        argv[40] = "-drive"
INFO    |        argv[41] = "if=none,index=4,id=vendor,if=none,file=C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\system-images\android-30\google_apis\x86\\vendor.img,read-only"
INFO    |        argv[42] = "-device"
INFO    |        argv[43] = "virtio-blk-pci,drive=vendor,modern-pio-notify"
INFO    |        argv[44] = "-drive"
INFO    |        argv[45] = "if=none,index=5,id=sdcard,if=none,file=C:\Users\username\.android\avd\pixel_5_-_api_30.avd\sdcard.img.qcow2,overlap-check=none,cache=unsafe,l2-cache-size=1048576"
INFO    |        argv[46] = "-device"
INFO    |        argv[47] = "virtio-blk-pci,drive=sdcard,modern-pio-notify"
INFO    |        argv[48] = "-netdev"
INFO    |        argv[49] = "user,id=mynet"
INFO    |        argv[50] = "-device"
INFO    |        argv[51] = "virtio-net-pci,netdev=mynet"
INFO    |        argv[52] = "-device"
INFO    |        argv[53] = "virtio-rng-pci"
INFO    |        argv[54] = "-show-cursor"
INFO    |        argv[55] = "-device"
INFO    |        argv[56] = "virtio_input_multi_touch_pci_1"
INFO    |        argv[57] = "-device"
INFO    |        argv[58] = "virtio_input_multi_touch_pci_2"
INFO    |        argv[59] = "-device"
INFO    |        argv[60] = "virtio_input_multi_touch_pci_3"
INFO    |        argv[61] = "-device"
INFO    |        argv[62] = "virtio_input_multi_touch_pci_4"
INFO    |        argv[63] = "-device"
INFO    |        argv[64] = "virtio_input_multi_touch_pci_5"
INFO    |        argv[65] = "-device"
INFO    |        argv[66] = "virtio_input_multi_touch_pci_6"
INFO    |        argv[67] = "-device"
INFO    |        argv[68] = "virtio_input_multi_touch_pci_7"
INFO    |        argv[69] = "-device"
INFO    |        argv[70] = "virtio_input_multi_touch_pci_8"
INFO    |        argv[71] = "-device"
INFO    |        argv[72] = "virtio_input_multi_touch_pci_9"
INFO    |        argv[73] = "-device"
INFO    |        argv[74] = "virtio_input_multi_touch_pci_10"
INFO    |        argv[75] = "-device"
INFO    |        argv[76] = "virtio_input_multi_touch_pci_11"
INFO    |        argv[77] = "-device"
INFO    |        argv[78] = "virtio-keyboard-pci"
INFO    |        argv[79] = "-L"
INFO    |        argv[80] = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator/lib/pc-bios"
INFO    |        argv[81] = "-soundhw"
INFO    |        argv[82] = "hda"
INFO    |        argv[83] = "-vga"
INFO    |        argv[84] = "none"
INFO    |        argv[85] = "-append"
INFO    |        argv[86] = "no_timer_check clocksource=pit console=ttyS0,38400 cma=296M@0-4G mac80211_hwsim.channels=2 loop.max_part=7 ramoops.mem_address=0xff018000 ramoops.mem_size=0x10000 memmap=0x10000$0xff018000 printk.devkmsg=on qemu=1 androidboot.hardware=ranchu androidboot.serialno=EMULATOR31X3X14X0 qemu.gles=1 qemu.settings.system.screen_off_timeout=2147483647 qemu.encrypt=1 qemu.vsync=60 qemu.gltransport=pipe qemu.gltransport.drawFlushInterval=800 qemu.opengles.version=196608 qemu.uirenderer=skiagl qemu.dalvik.vm.heapsize=512m qemu.camera_protocol_ver=1 qemu.camera_hq_edge_processing=0 androidboot.vbmeta.size=6144 androidboot.vbmeta.hash_alg=sha256 androidboot.vbmeta.digest=ea5843921b6671f2d851ebf15e7b55f71e73fc36967778bca3be3e3cf4e15f28 androidboot.boot_devices=pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0 qemu.wifi=1 qemu.hwcodec.avcdec=2 qemu.hwcodec.vpxdec=2 android.qemud=1 qemu.avd_name=pixel_5_-_api_30"
INFO    |        argv[87] = "-android-hw"
INFO    |        argv[88] = "C:\Users\username\.android\avd\pixel_5_-_api_30.avd\hardware-qemu.ini"
INFO    | Concatenated QEMU options: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe" -dns-server 10.10.10.228 -mem-path C:\Users\username\.android\avd\pixel_5_-_api_30.avd\snapshots\default_boot\ram.img -mem-file-shared -serial con: -device goldfish_pstore,addr=0xff018000,size=0x10000,file=C:\Users\username\.android\avd\pixel_5_-_api_30.avd\data\misc\pstore\pstore.bin -cpu android64 -enable-hax -smp cores=4 -m 2048 -lcd-density 440 -nodefaults -kernel "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\system-images\android-30\google_apis\x86\\kernel-ranchu-64" -initrd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\system-images\android-30\google_apis\x86\\ramdisk.img" -drive "if=none,index=0,id=system,if=none,file=C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\system-images\android-30\google_apis\x86\\system.img,read-only" -device virtio-blk-pci,drive=system,modern-pio-notify -drive if=none,index=1,id=cache,if=none,file=C:\Users\username\.android\avd\pixel_5_-_api_30.avd\cache.img.qcow2,overlap-check=none,cache=unsafe,l2-cache-size=1048576 -device virtio-blk-pci,drive=cache,modern-pio-notify -drive if=none,index=2,id=userdata,if=none,file=C:\Users\username\.android\avd\pixel_5_-_api_30.avd\userdata-qemu.img.qcow2,overlap-check=none,cache=unsafe,l2-cache-size=1048576 -device virtio-blk-pci,drive=userdata,modern-pio-notify -drive if=none,index=3,id=encrypt,if=none,file=C:\Users\username\.android\avd\pixel_5_-_api_30.avd\encryptionkey.img.qcow2,overlap-check=none,cache=unsafe,l2-cache-size=1048576 -device virtio-blk-pci,drive=encrypt,modern-pio-notify -drive "if=none,index=4,id=vendor,if=none,file=C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\system-images\android-30\google_apis\x86\\vendor.img,read-only" -device virtio-blk-pci,drive=vendor,modern-pio-notify -drive if=none,index=5,id=sdcard,if=none,file=C:\Users\username\.android\avd\pixel_5_-_api_30.avd\sdcard.img.qcow2,overlap-check=none,cache=unsafe,l2-cache-size=1048576 -device virtio-blk-pci,drive=sdcard,modern-pio-notify -netde
VERBOSE | Android qemu version 31.3.14.0 (build_id 9322596) (CL:N/A)
VERBOSE | Starting QEMU main loop
VERBOSE | android_fopen: Failed to open /qemu.conf, err: 2
VERBOSE | Adding boot property: 'ro.opengles.version' = '196608'
VERBOSE | Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.fake_camera' = 'front'
VERBOSE | Adding boot property: 'qemu.adb.secure' = '1'
VERBOSE | Adding boot property: 'dalvik.vm.heapsize' = '512m'
VERBOSE | Adding boot property: 'qemu.hw.mainkeys' = '0'
VERBOSE | Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.lcd_density' = '440'
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
VERBOSE | control console listening on port 5554, ADB on port 5555
VERBOSE | goldfish_events.have-dpad: false
VERBOSE | goldfish_events.have-trackball: false
VERBOSE | goldfish_events.have-camera: true
VERBOSE | goldfish_events.have-keyboard: false
VERBOSE | goldfish_events.have-lidswitch: false
VERBOSE | goldfish_events.have-tabletmode: false
VERBOSE | goldfish_events.have-touch: false
VERBOSE | goldfish_events.have-multitouch: false
VERBOSE | Adding boot property: 'net.wifi_mac_prefix' = '5554'
dsound: Could not initialize DirectSoundCapture
dsound: Reason: No sound driver is available for use, or the given GUID is not a valid DirectSound device ID
VERBOSE | Not using any http proxy
VERBOSE | Adding boot property: 'qemu.timezone' = 'America/New_York'
VERBOSE | android_hw_fingerprint_init: fingerprint qemud listen service initialized
WARNING | *** No gRPC protection active, consider launching with the -grpc-use-jwt flag.***
INFO    | Started GRPC server at 127.0.0.1:8554, security: Local, auth: none
INFO    | Advertising in: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\avd\running\pid_7716.ini
Attempt to initialize voice without DirectSoundCapture object
Attempt to initialize voice without DirectSoundCapture object
Failed to create voice `adc'
Failed to sync vcpu reg
Failed to sync vcpu reg
Failed to sync vcpu reg
Failed to sync vcpu reg
Failed to sync vcpu reg
VERBOSE | emulator_window_fb_rotate
INFO    | setDisplayConfigs w 1080 h 2340 dpiX 440 dpiY 440
VERBOSE | config multidisplay with config.ini 0x0 0x0 0x0
VERBOSE | No acpi ini file provided, using default
Failed to sync vcpu reg
Failed to sync vcpu reg
Failed to sync vcpu reg
Failed to sync vcpu reg
Failed to sync vcpu reg
Failed to sync vcpu reg
Failed to sync vcpu reg
Failed to sync vcpu reg
Failed to sync vcpu reg
Failed to sync vcpu reg
VCPU shutdown request
VERBOSE | Saving state on exit with session uptime 202 ms
VCPU shutdown request
VERBOSE |  no root specified:
VERBOSE | Path:C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe protocol version: 41
VERBOSE | Found: 1 adb executables
VERBOSE | Adb: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
VERBOSE | Path:C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe protocol version: 41
VERBOSE | Done with QEMU main loop
VERBOSE | User configuration saved to C:\Users\username\.android\avd\pixel_5_-_api_30.avd\emulator-user.ini
VERBOSE | Adb transition disconnected -> disconnected
```

I have searched and tried every solution for "failed to sync vcpu reg", "error while loading state for instance 0x0 of device 'goldfish_pipe'", but nothing has worked for me.  If I uninstall HAXM, the emulator runs albeit incredibly slowly.  If I install HAXM, the emulator crashes every time.

I suspected this may have had something to do with installing VirtualBox, but uninstalling that had no effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seemingly contradictory to all of the information on the internet that says otherwise, enabling Virtual Machine Platform in Windows features fixed the issue.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/67664072/8169306

Credit to @angry_chloro_man for this solution.