# Android Studio Emulator not working with Vanguard

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

The title may seem rhetorical given that solutions for this problem already exist

but, my problem is a bit different, in that my emulator still terminates after uninstalling vgc service and vgk as well so idk what's the problem anymore and change logs show

```
Emulator: Pixel 6 API 29 - Failed to sync vcpu reg
```

this and the solution was to make sure I don't have any VM's running which I'm pretty sure are not running

Edit: I tried running Gennymotion and that too did not work as well...
[if this helps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uatil.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember spending half a day in 2020 trying to find out why my emulators stopped working... I'm really impressed that this is still an issue in 2023.

###### Update

It seems that uninstalling Vanguard also disables Window's Virtual Machine Platform, to re-enable it follow the instructions described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67664072/2115403):

1. Right-click on the Start menu button and select `Apps and Features`
2. Select `Programs and Features` on the right under related settings
3. Select the checkbox [Virtual Machine Platform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sjjk.png)

If you haven't uninstalled Vanguard yet or you are still unsure about it, read the original answer. In any case, first uninstall Vanguard completely and then enable Windows' feature.

###### Original Aswer

Check the following,

1. You completely uninstalled Vanguard
2. **You restarted your PC** afterward
3. **VGC and VGK services are no longer running**
4. You created a new emulator, just to be sure

If all fail give Riot's [**Manual** Uninstall Guide](https://support-valorant.riotgames.com/hc/en-us/articles/360044648213-Uninstalling-and-Disabling-Riot-Vanguard) a try.

Comment: I did all that I even uninstalled bluestacks to not have any emulator so as to not obstruct the AVD and even then it just gets terminated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67664072/2115403 ?

Comment: Great to hear! I've updated the answer to include this scenario as well.

Comment: Update:- I have found a way to run Vanguard without it making problems with the AVD emulator basically follow all of these steps create new devices and then opening them and close all of them then you can go open valorant and it will reinstall vanguard for the user then restart the computer after this the emulator will start from a saved state and not run into issues with vanguard so long as you don't cold boot the emulator and uncheck the default cold boot in advanced emulator settings :D