# Android Studio Avd failing to run

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

Please assist. I have installed android studio on my windows 10 and create a virtual device but when i try to start the avd i get the error "Error while waiting for device: The emulator process for AVD Pixel_4_API_30 has terminated.". I have also checked the idea.log and i saw the error below

```
INFO -       Emulator: Nexus 6 API 33 - C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Nexus_6_API_33 -qt-hide-window -grpc-use-token -idle-grpc-timeout 300 
2022-07-20 11:40:25,769 [2710021]   WARN -       Emulator: Nexus 6 API 33 - unexpected system image feature string, emulator might not function correctly, please try updating the emulator. 
2022-07-20 11:40:27,632 [2711884]  ERROR -       Emulator: Nexus 6 API 33 - Failed to open /qemu.conf, err: 2 
2022-07-20 11:40:27,632 [2711884]  ERROR -       Emulator: Nexus 6 API 33 - Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1 Patch 1  Build #AI-212.5712.43.2112.8609683 
2022-07-20 11:40:27,632 [2711884]  ERROR -       Emulator: Nexus 6 API 33 - JDK: 11.0.12; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: Oracle Corporation 
2022-07-20 11:40:27,632 [2711884]  ERROR -       Emulator: Nexus 6 API 33 - OS: Windows 10 
2022-07-20 11:40:27,632 [2711884]  ERROR -       Emulator: Nexus 6 API 33 - Last Action: Android.RunAndroidSdkManager 
2022-07-20 11:40:27,639 [2711891]   INFO -       Emulator: Nexus 6 API 33 - added library vulkan-1.dll 
2022-07-20 11:40:27,639 [2711891]   INFO -       Emulator: Nexus 6 API 33 - configAndStartRenderer: setting vsync to 60 hz 
2022-07-20 11:40:27,639 [2711891]   INFO -       Emulator: Nexus 6 API 33 - Sending adb public key [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 @unknown] 
2022-07-20 11:40:27,639 [2711891]   INFO -       Emulator: Nexus 6 API 33 - Rootcanal has  been activated. 
2022-07-20 11:40:27,639 [2711891]   INFO -       Emulator: Nexus 6 API 33 - HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode. 
2022-07-20 11:40:28,684 [2712936]   INFO - b.PhysicalDeviceChangeListener - emulator-5554 connected 
2022-07-20 11:40:28,690 [2712942]   INFO -       Emulator: Nexus 6 API 33 - Started GRPC server at 127.0.0.1:8554, security: Local+token 
2022-07-20 11:40:28,691 [2712943]   INFO -       Emulator: Nexus 6 API 33 - Advertising in: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\avd\running\pid_15824.ini 
2022-07-20 11:40:28,692 [2712944]   INFO -       Emulator: Nexus 6 API 33 - Failed to sync vcpu reg 
2022-07-20 11:40:28,725 [2712977]   INFO -       Emulator: Nexus 6 API 33 - Failed to sync vcpu reg 
2022-07-20 11:40:28,725 [2712977]   INFO -       Emulator: Nexus 6 API 33 - Failed to sync vcp 
2022-07-20 11:40:28,725 [2712977]   INFO -       Emulator: Nexus 6 API 33 - u reg 
2022-07-20 11:40:28,725 [2712977]   INFO -       Emulator: Nexus 6 API 33 - Failed to sync vcpu reg 
2022-07-20 11:40:28,725 [2712977]   INFO -       Emulator: Nexus 6 API 33 - Failed to sync vcpu reg 
2022-07-20 11:40:28,758 [2713010]   INFO -       Emulator: Nexus 6 API 33 - Failed to sync vcpu reg 
2022-07-20 11:40:28,758 [2713010]   INFO -       Emulator: Nexus 6 API 33 - Failed to sync vcpu reg 
2022-07-20 11:40:28,759 [2713011]   INFO -       Emulator: Nexus 6 API 33 - Failed to sync vcpu reg 
2022-07-20 11:40:28,759 [2713011]   INFO -       Emulator: Nexus 6 API 33 - Failed to sync vcpu reg 
2022-07-20 11:40:28,767 [2713019]   INFO -       Emulator: Nexus 6 API 33 - VCPU shutdown request 
2022-07-20 11:40:28,767 [2713019]   INFO -       Emulator: Nexus 6 API 33 - VCPU shutdown request 
2022-07-20 11:40:28,767 [2713019]   INFO -       Emulator: Nexus 6 API 33 - VCPU shutdown request 
2022-07-20 11:40:29,221 [2713473]   INFO -       Emulator: Nexus 6 API 33 - Shutting down gRPC endpoin 
2022-07-20 11:40:29,221 [2713473]   INFO -       Emulator: Nexus 6 API 33 - t 
2022-07-20 11:40:29,224 [2713476]   INFO -       Emulator: Nexus 6 API 33 - Shutting down gRPC endpoint 
2022-07-20 11:40:29,258 [2713510]   INFO -       Emulator: Nexus 6 API 33 - Closing down rootcanal. 
2022-07-20 11:40:30,378 [2714630]   INFO -       Emulator: Nexus 6 API 33 - Android emulator version 31.2.10.0 (build_id 8420304) (CL:N/A) 
2022-07-20 11:40:30,401 [2714653]   INFO -       Emulator: Nexus 6 API 33 - Process finished with exit code 0 
2022-07-20 11:40:30,608 [2714860]   INFO - b.PhysicalDeviceChangeListener - emulator-5554 disconnected
```

I saw one solution suggesting i create the qemu.conf file and put in C drive but its not working.
I am running android studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1 Patch 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after thorough search on the net i saw a solution that helped, my problem was coming from HP Sure click and HP Wolf security, I just turn off HP Sure click, HP wolf security threat containment and restarted my machine. For reference check the answers on the question on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17024538/how-do-i-fix-failed-to-sync-vcpu-reg-error)

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the graphic of your emulator from automatic to Software

[image]

Comment: still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

For me the following steps worked:

1. `cd C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator`
2. run `emulator -accel-check` and follow the instructions.
3. reinstall intel HAMX from `C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager`.

Comment: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager doesn't exists on my machine.

Comment: This is an example, it may be different on your computer. User is your username. If Intel x86 emulator accelerator (HAXM installer) not selected in Android Studio settings on the path: File | Settings | Appearance & Behavior | System Settings | Android SDK | SDK  Tools, folder may not exist.

Comment: okay thank you. I managed to resolve the issue by turning off HP Wolf Security and HP Sure click