# Error launching Tizen TV Emulator on Win 10

Tags: tizen, tizen-emulator

when i try to run tizen Tv emulator(the mobile emulator works) i get this error "-enable-whpx: invalid option".
i worked with the same computer for 2 weeks and the emulator works but now it shows me that error.
i tried following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75454053/error-launching-tizen-tv-emulator-on-win-11-enable-whpx-invalid-option)
but sadly my computer doesn't have intel HAXM
[image]
[image]

This is my emulator.log file:

```
07:15:18.786| 5132|I|    osutil| 396|Running with elevated integrity level. Try to respawn.
07:15:18.791| 5132|I|    osutil| 427|Respawning success. Waiting for child process.
07:15:18.806| 3180|I|      main| 345|Start emulator...
qemu args: =========================================
"C:\tizen-studio\platforms\tizen-7.0\tv-samsung\emulator\bin\\emulator-x86_64" "-drive" "file=C:\tizen-studio-data\emulator\vms\T-samsung-7.0-x86\emulimg-T-samsung-7.0-x86.x86,if=none,index=0,cache.no-flush=on,id=drive" "-device" "virtio-blk-pci,drive=drive" "-drive" "file=C:\tizen-studio-data\emulator\vms\T-samsung-7.0-x86\swap-T-samsung-7.0-x86.img,if=none,index=1,id=swap" "-device" "virtio-blk-pci,drive=swap" "-enable-whpx" "-device" "vigs,backend=gl,wsi=vigs_wsi" "-device" "yagl,wsi=vigs_wsi" "-smp" "4" "-m" "1024" "-device" "maru-virtual-tuner,system=ATSC,country=USA,table=C:\tizen-studio-data\emulator\vms\T-samsung-7.0-x86\tuner_default.cfg,stillimg=C:\tizen-studio\platforms\tizen-7.0\tv-samsung\emulator-resources\images,wsi=vigs_wsi" "-net" "nic,model=virtio" "-net" "user" "-chardev" "file,path=C:\tizen-studio-data\emulator\vms\T-samsung-7.0-x86\logs\emulator.klog,id=con0" "-device" "isa-serial,chardev=con0" "-device" "virtio-serial" "-L" "C:\tizen-studio\platforms/tizen-7.0/tv-samsung/emulator\data\bios" "-kernel" "C:\tizen-studio\platforms/tizen-7.0/tv-samsung/emulator\data\kernel\bzImage.x86" "-append" "vm_name=T-samsung-7.0-x86 video=LVDS-1:1920x1080-32@60 dpi=72 clocksource=hpet consoleblank=0  host_ip=10.0.2.2 console=ttyS0 model=4ksero yagl=1 force_pat" "-device" "virtio-maru-touchscreen-pci,max_point=10" "-nodefaults" "-device" "virtio-maru-esm-pci" "-device" "virtio-maru-hwkey-pci" "-device" "virtio-maru-evdi-pci" "-device" "virtio-maru-motor-pci" "-device" "virtio-maru-keyboard-pci" "-rtc" "base=utc" "-M" "maru-x86-machine" "-soundhw" "all" "-usb" "-vga" "none" "-device" "maru-external-input-pci,stillimg=C:\tizen-studio\platforms\tizen-7.0\tv-samsung\emulator-resources\images,wsi=vigs_wsi" "-display" "maru_qt,rendering=onscreen,resolution=1920x1080,dpi=72" 
====================================================
07:15:18.806| 3180|I|      main| 348|qemu main start...
07:15:18.808| 3180|I|qt5_msgbox|  69|qt5_msgbox starts... 
07:15:18.808| 3180|I|qt5_msgbox|  63|qt5_msgbox path : C:\tizen-studio\platforms\tizen-7.0\tv-samsung\emulator\bin\qt5_msgbox
07:15:18.833| 3180|I|      main|  91|Exit emulator...
C:\tizen-studio\platforms\tizen-7.0\tv-samsung\emulator\bin\\emulator-x86_64: -enable-whpx: invalid option

enter code here
enter code here
```

Comment: I have docker installed (i unstalled it now and rcomputer), i tried to uninstall and re-install tizen sdk too 
but none of them worked

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for updating it.

I think that it might be a similar [Error launching Tizen TV Emulator on Win 11 "-enable-whpx: invalid option"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75454053/error-launching-tizen-tv-emulator-on-win-11-enable-whpx-invalid-option)

I am guessing your situation is that your pc has not been installed haxm yet.

Then,
Could you share the log file?
Ex) E:\tizen-studio-data\emulator\vms\t-0626-1\logs\emulator.log, emulator.klog

Thanks

Comment: i added it to the question.

Comment: well i tried following the steps in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75454053/error-launching-tizen-tv-emulator-on-win-11-enable-whpx-invalid-option as i said i event uninstalled and re-installed tizen SDK but none of them works i even uninstalled docker because it use virtualisation too so i guessed that it may cause a problem but still get the same error trying to launch tizenTV emulator